# media queries not triggered when navigation back on smartphone

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a website responsive. The header should be 100% of the page width, on all devices, so I set the width like so:

```
width:100%;
```

It works perfectly well on all devices, however on smartphones, it only works the first time you visit a page. If you click on a link on the page and then click "back", the website "blows up", and is show completely wrong, and the header is definately not 100%.

Has anyone else ever had this problem?

First time you visit the page:
[image: First load]

When you go to another page and then click "back" to this page:
[image: When you go back]

I talking about the area with the red border that currently has no styling other than the red border.

Problem persists both with or without

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your viewport settings.  They should be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

Comment: But I have a completely different page where I don't use the viewport meta tag att all, and the header never changes just because I navigate "back" on those pages?

Comment: You need to use viewport to control any kind of scaling, especially on smart phones.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"> Doesn't solve the problem. instead the header is now show with a width of 100% of the screen, but the page has lots of emtpy space next to it and I can't zoom out etc. :/  (this only happends when I "go back". As before the page works fine when loaded the first time.

Comment: Your question asked for "The header should be 100% of the page width" and I provided a solution to which you are saying, "Doesn't solve the problem. instead the header is now show with a width of 100% of the screen."  What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear. The header is 100%, but the content below the header is "cut in the middle", and I have to scroll sideways.

Comment: @Alisso please post your HTML with CSS on jsFiddle or Codepen.

Comment: When I made a fiddle, I think the fiddle overrides my head. :/ I'm not able to reproduce it with a fiddle. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @JHangweb it seems my mobile used an older cached version of the css.. I reset two commits, refreshed and stuff, and now it's back to normal :)